# Selecting XML tags with <bar:foo> markup using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, xml-parsing

I have been googling for hours for solutions but found none that targets my specific problem.

I have been experimenting with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/profinsights/uploads',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml    
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    var entrynode = xml.getElementsByTagName("entry");
    $(entrynode).each(function() {
        //console.log($(this));
        console.log($('id',this)); //matches <id successfully
        console.log($('media:group',this)); // no match
    });
}
```

**XML fragment:**

```
...

<entry>
  <id>​http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/870MupRJhmU​</id>​
  <title type=​"text">​PIMS Humble Beginnings​</title>​
  <author>​…​</author>​
  <gd:comments>​…​</gd:comments>​
  <media:group>​
    <media:category label=​"Education" scheme=​"http:​/​/​gdata.youtube.com/​schemas/​2007/​categories.cat">​Education​</media:category>​
    <media:content url=​"https:​/​/​www.youtube.com/​v/​870MupRJhmU?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata" type=​"application/​x-shockwave-flash" medium=​"video" isDefault=​"true" expression=​"full" duration=​"561" yt:format=​"5">​</media:content>​
    <media:content url=​"rtsp:​/​/​v3.cache3.c.youtube.com/​CigLENy73wIaHwllhkmUugy98xMYDSANFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/​0/​0/​0/​video.3gp" type=​"video/​3gpp" medium=​"video" expression=​"full" duration=​"561" yt:format=​"1">​</media:content>​
    <media:content url=​"rtsp:​/​/​v1.cache7.c.youtube.com/​CigLENy73wIaHwllhkmUugy98xMYESARFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/​0/​0/​0/​video.3gp" type=​"video/​3gpp" medium=​"video" expression=​"full" duration=​"561" yt:format=​"6">​</media:content>​
    <media:description type=​"plain">​…​</media:description>​
    <media:keywords>​…​</media:keywords>​
    <media:player url=​"https:​/​/​www.youtube.com/​watch?v=870MupRJhmU&feature=youtube_gdata_player">​</media:player>​
    <media:thumbnail url=​"http:​/​/​i.ytimg.com/​vi/​870MupRJhmU/​0.jpg" height=​"360" width=​"480" time=​"00:​04:​40.500">​</media:thumbnail>​
    <media:thumbnail url=​"http:​/​/​i.ytimg.com/​vi/​870MupRJhmU/​1.jpg" height=​"90" width=​"120" time=​"00:​02:​20.250">​</media:thumbnail>​
    <media:thumbnail url=​"http:​/​/​i.ytimg.com/​vi/​870MupRJhmU/​2.jpg" height=​"90" width=​"120" time=​"00:​04:​40.500">​</media:thumbnail>​
    <media:thumbnail url=​"http:​/​/​i.ytimg.com/​vi/​870MupRJhmU/​3.jpg" height=​"90" width=​"120" time=​"00:​07:​00.750">​</media:thumbnail>​
    <media:title type=​"plain">​PIMS Humble Beginnings​</media:title>​
    <yt:duration seconds=​"561">​</yt:duration>​
  </media:group>
​</entry>

...
```

- My goal is to get the text nodes and attributes from each node named
  like `<media:foo>`
- I know my selector for matching the node
  **media:group** is wrong, and hopefully experts in xml selectors can give me an advice on how to handle this.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Btw, here is the fiddle for the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/vYJwm/

**UPDATE**:

- I applied a code revision as suggested by Rob here:
  http://jsfiddle.net/vYJwm/1/ but the console log gave an empty result.
- I guess the console logger is not giving me the correct result.
- Implemented a solution by antwarpes here: [$(xml).find('someElement') :  pulling values with jquery from xml with Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10181087)

**Problem solved**. Thanks guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML JQuery Ajax Response with Namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625487/parsing-xml-jquery-ajax-response-with-namespace) - Applied to your case, use `$('media\\:group',this)`.

Comment: @RobW something is wrong, I updated my code as per your advice, but console log outputs empty. Am not sure what is wrong. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vYJwm/1/

Comment: @RobW I noticed, Google Chrome's console logger is not giving me the expected output, so I tried redirecting the result to the document <body>, and it's giving me the expected output here: http://jsfiddle.net/vYJwm/4/ THANKS AGAIN ROB.

Comment: You may now vote to close this question. Thanks guys!

Comment: Your fiddle does not show anything in Chromium 20. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1601610 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10181087

Comment: @RobW yes, seems the code breaks in Chrome, I tested in FF and it is working. Implemented using artwarps solution, seems working. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/vYJwm/3/

jQuery isn't parsing them as `media:foo` but more `foo`.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks, but that is not my goal. Rob W already gave the solution. Thanks again.